# 8051 external interrupt INT0 issue?

Tags: interrupts, 8051

How do I write an ISR greater than 8 bytes which is triggered by INT0?

Comment: You place a jump instruction at the address of the interrupt handler, which then allows the actual handler code to be placed anywhere in memory where there's enough room for it.

Comment: ORG 0003H ; LJMP START;  RETI like this?

Comment: What is that RETI for at that place? There is no return from a jump, so the RETI must be at the end of the code that you jump to.

Answer (score 2):

Your code jumps to the ISR which ends in a RETI:

```
    org 0003H
    jmp isr

    ; ...

isr:
    ; any instruction you need
    reti
```

If you program in C, this will be handled for you automatically. For example, Keil-C51 places ISRs right at the start address if there is enough room, or jumps to it if not.